# Make bootstrap timepicker popup on input click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am tried to create a timepicker 
using this [here](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

then I implemented  its js and css in my project.
but when I click it the popup didn't appear

I just have this code and can't add anew control to the glyphicons

```
TextBox control = new TextBox { ID = _TimeFieldID + item.BlueprintFieldId, CausesValidation = true, EnableViewState = true, CssClass = "form-control timepicker margin-top-none metadatacontrol", Width = new Unit(ctrWidth + "%") };
```

and fire it in javascript with

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker();
```

how can I make it appears popup in textbox click?
How can ovride the js to get timepicker fire on a click in the input field?
any help?

**EDIT:**
Here is my new javascript calling

```
  $(".timepicker").timepicker();    
    $('.timepicker').click(function () { 
        $('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu').show(); 
    });
```

Now I can show the timepicker popup , but it looks very wide 
I try this

```
  $('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu').css("display", "inline-block");
```

This code displays the popup. Now, the pop-up window width needs to be set the same as width of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this javascript

```
$('.timepicker').focus(function (){
$('.timepicker').timepicker('showWidget');

});
```

or

```
$('.timepicker').click(function (){
$('.timepicker').timepicker('showWidget');

});
```

after your code

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker();
```

Comment: it seems like there is no difference , if it was in or out document.ready

Comment: did you add bootstrap-timepicker.css ?